# Android onBackPressed, how to test if unsaved changes *actually* made?

Tags: android, listener

I've searched at length and tried the usual suspects, but it's time to ask for help.

My Android activity loads EditText, Spinner and CheckBox values from SQLite happily enough.

The problem is sensing if the user thereafter **actually changes a value** so I can warn at onBackPressed if unsaved changes were made (i.e. s/he had not hit the 'Save' button).

For example, with an EditText I've tried:

- using a TextWatcher.onTextChanged listener, but it gets fired when the EditText is first instantiated, which makes setting a 'data changed' flag meaningless
- trapping the various KEY_DOWN events for the DONE, ENTER, NEXT and DEL keys, but with mixed results that wouldn't help with my Spinners and CheckBoxes anyway
- onTouchListener (I think, but I'm a little foggy by now), to no avail

I guess what I'm looking for is a View class listener, attached only after the activity has settled down, that fires for subsequent state changes. But, nothing I've searched for fits the bill.

How do others handle this problem?

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: I was hoping this weeks Google I/O would announce some related SDK features, maybe in ViewGroup handling, but I didn't see anything germane. Back in the 70's, we simply OR'd the event flags set by the individual asynchronous IO completions and go for coffee. Is there really no modern equivalent facility on Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of any general mechanism that could apply to all kinds of widgets.

Nevertheless, a cleaner solution would be :

- to have a model (POJO) that represents all data you display on screen
- every change in widgets are reflected in the model
- every time a setter is called in the POJO, it compares the new set value with the old one
- if a change is made, then it raises an internal flag.
- if the flag is raised at onBackPressed, then you show an AlertDialogFragment asking whether changed values should be saved or not.